# No service was found matching the request

Tags: web-services, soapui

I am trying to test a webservice using soapUI and getting response as :

```
     <faultstring>No service was found matching the request</faultstring>
```

Please let me know how can i overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint is probably wrong.  Sometimes WSDLs use the option to generate default endpoints, and they may or may not be valid.  So you need to check them before trusting them.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  i was using soapui 4.5.1 version, but after further googling i found that soapui 4.5.0 wil work better. i reverted back to the previous version and i am getting the response wherein it has "<axis2ns213:severity>ERROR</axis2ns213:severity>
".  Please let me know what wud hv went wrong.  thanks once again.

Comment: You should consult the documentation for the service to see what provides that error.